# Asp.NET Principal WebORB HttpHandler

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, weborb, iprincipal

I have a Flex-WebORB-Asp.NET application. When logging in, there's an AuthenticationHandler which implements a WebORB interface:

```
IPrincipal CheckCredentials(string username, string password, Request message);
```

So I create a Principal and return it. WebORB uses the Principal to check for Authentication and Authorization of remote method calls.

```
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user.id.ToString()), new[] { "admin" });
return principal
```

Now, at this point, if I check what `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` is, it's a WindowsIdentity.

So far so good. When later on, a remote call is done through WebORB, I get the id of the logged in user by calling:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

So I guess WebORB makes sure the Identity of the Thread is set with each remote call.

Problem is that when I call a HttpHandler (to retrieve an image), I also try to get the id of the logged in user with `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`, but that doesn't work. Probably because with a HttpHandler, WebORB doesn't come into action.

How would you solve this so that I can get the id of the logged in user the same way in both cases? Put it in a session object? Can you change the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`? Shouldn't the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` be the same as the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`?

ps: The users are not in Active Directory.

Answer (score 1):

No, [they are different](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx).